# mysql stored function case statement

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

I'm building a stored function to return the significant figures from a float.. eg sfround(4.867,2) would return 4.8, sfround(1345,2) would return 1300

The sample code is

```
delimiter //

CREATE FUNCTION sfround(n FLOAT, sf INT) RETURNS FLOAT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
CASE n
WHEN 0 THEN RETURN 0;
ELSE
BEGIN
RETURN ROUND(n ,sf-FLOOR(LOG10(ABS(n ))))
END;
END CASE;
END//

delimiter ;
```

(I learnt indents cause mysql to have issues)

I throws an error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END;
END CASE;
END' at line 8
```

This is my first time writing such a beast and have no idea where to start..

Comment: The reason you have a syntax error is that you are missing a `;` at the end of `RETURN ROUND(n ,sf-FLOOR(LOG10(ABS(n ))))`

Comment: <facepalm> thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SQLs `CASE` as a single expression, which returns a single value. It's not used like `IF` or `switch/case` in procedural languages (Though you can [do that too](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html)). It is more functional style. So what you might need is:

```
delimiter //

CREATE FUNCTION sfround(n FLOAT, sf INT) RETURNS FLOAT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  RETURN CASE n
    WHEN 0 THEN 0
    ELSE ROUND(n ,sf-FLOOR(LOG10(ABS(n ))))
  END;
END//

delimiter ;
```

Note that for single-statement procedures or functions you don't need to change the delimiter. It could also be just

```
CREATE FUNCTION sfround(n FLOAT, sf INT) RETURNS FLOAT DETERMINISTIC
  RETURN CASE n
    WHEN 0 THEN 0
    ELSE ROUND(n ,sf-FLOOR(LOG10(ABS(n ))))
  END;
```

Also note that I only address the syntax error. Not the used algorithm.

Comment: This is *not* true, there is a `CASE` statement specifically for stored functions. See the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html). OPs code is perfectly fine other than a missing `;` at the end of one line.

Comment: Thanks @Nick - You're right. But at the same time it wasn't technically wrong what I wrote previously: "In **SQL** ..." - For pure SQL it's true :-) I still have changed the text and linked the "CASE **statement**".

Comment: Yes, I should have been specific that it is a MySQL feature